# Obtaining the collection of jline3 commands from a TreeCompleter

Tags: java, scala, jline, jline3

I have a `TreeCompleter` (Scala code) which works as expected:

```
val treeCompleter = new TreeCompleter(
    node("bindkey"),
    node("cls"),
    node(
      "custom",
      node("Option1", node("Param1", "Param2")),
      node("Option2"),
      node("Option3")
    ),
    node("help"),
    node("set"),
    node("testkey"),
    node("tput")
)
```

How can I obtain the collection of command names? For this example, those names are: `bindkey`, `cls`, `custom`, `help`, `set`, `testkey` and `tput`.

The github project that contains the above code is here: https://github.com/mslinn/jline-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/CliLoop.scala

I don't care if the answer is in Java or Scala, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible this way given that `TreeCompleter` is just a [wrapper](https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/b50c10392c8721eeb92ab7cd0dd666c47fe4918e/builtins/src/main/java/org/jline/builtins/Completers.java#L372) around `RegexCompleter` that actually does the job. So if you want to gather this information, you should do it before you pass your nodes to the `TreeCompleter` constructor or probably before you create `TreeCompleter.Node` instances because they seem to provide no public accessors. One obvious solution would be to create your own wrapper around `TreeCompleter` with your own inner `Node` class that would store this information for later usage.

Comment: [Here is some Scala code](https://github.com/mslinn/cli-loop/blob/rework/src/main/scala/com/micronautics/cli/CNodes.scala#L19) that uses a `CNode` to define structure, and is then translated to recursive `node` invocations. The key is this implicit conversion: implicit def cNodeToNode(cNode: CNode): Node = node(cNode.name :: cNode.children.cNodes.map(cNodeToNode).toList: _*)